# get result from public static string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is there a simple way to get the public static string result to the controller.

So im trying to make so when you upload you're image it gets resized.
i made a following code in my Toolbox

```
public static string ImageUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string SubFolder)
{
    Guid gi = Guid.NewGuid();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

    using (var image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, true, true))
    {
        var thumbWidth = 700;
        var thumbHeight = 700;
        if (image.Width < image.Height)
        {
            //portrait image  
            thumbHeight = 640;
            var imgRatio = (float)thumbHeight / (float)image.Height;
            thumbWidth = Convert.ToInt32(image.Width * imgRatio);
        }
        else
        if (image.Height < image.Width)
        {
            //landscape image  
            thumbWidth = 960;
            var imgRatio = (float)thumbWidth / (float)image.Width;
            thumbHeight = Convert.ToInt32(image.Height * imgRatio);
        }

        using (var thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(
            thumbWidth,
            thumbHeight,
            () => false,
            IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            var jpgInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                .Where(codecInfo => codecInfo.MimeType == "image/jpeg").First();

            using (var encParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
            {
                string thumbPath = "~/Content/admin/images/" + SubFolder;
                bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(thumbPath));

                if (!isExists)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(thumbPath));
                }

                var thumbPathFull = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(thumbPath), gi + extension);
                string newfileurl = "/Content/admin/images/" + SubFolder + gi + extension;
                long quality = 1500;
                encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
                thumb.Save(thumbPathFull, jpgInfo, encParams);
                return newfileurl;
            }
        }
    }
```

so i want the value "return newfileurl;" to my controller so how do i call it. so i can save the the string to my db to get the image frontend

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult NewsCreate(NewsItem ni, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        Guid gi = Guid.NewGuid();
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            CRUDHelper.ImageUpload(file, "newsimage");
        ni.Image = **??????insert solution here??????**;
        db.NewsItems.Add(ni);
        db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: `CRUDHelper.ImageUpload(file, "newsimage");` already *returns* the result, you only have to assign it to something: `ni.Image = CRUDHelper.ImageUpload(file, "newsimage");`

Comment: Oh thank you i wil try this

Comment: thanks HimBromBeere this works!

Comment: strange mental block you had here about this one, since it's just a simple variable assignment (albeit using the result of a method instead of a hard-coded value), and you do that exact thing (including returning the results of methods) in lots of other places in the code above. The fact the method is static makes no particular difference to the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRUDHelper.ImageUpload(file, "newsimage"); already returns the result, you only have to assign it to something: ni.Image = CRUDHelper.ImageUpload(file, "newsimage");

– HimBromBeere